# Limit to one post for each custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I created 4 custom post types.

Each author can write 1 post in each custom post type.

When an author wrote 1 post in a custom post type, I would like to remove "Add new.. (CPT)" for the custom post type concerned in admin menu.

For the moment, the limitation of 1 post works fine but I can't delete "Add new...(CPT)" in the admin menu.

Can I have some help please ?

```
$post_types_name = array('subject-imposed', 'subject-free', 'dissertation', 'curriculum-vitae');

foreach ($post_types_name as $post_type_name) {
    $count_post = count_user_posts(get_current_user_id(), $post_type_name, true);

    $max_posts = 1; //the number of max published posts

    if ($count_post >= $max_posts) {
        add_action( 'admin_menu', function() use ( $post_type_name ) {
                remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type='.$post_type_name, 'post-new.php?post_type='.$post_type_name );
            }
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE :**

Based on this hook

```
function remove_submenu() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=posttype', 'post-new.php?post_type=posttype' );
}

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_submenu', 999 );
```

Comment: 1 post per CPT? or 1 post per author per CPT? Each has a very different answer, can you edit your question to make it clear which you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Each author can post 1 post per CPT. I created 4 CPT, so 4 posts for each author. Sorry I will update

Comment: On what hook is this code firing?

Comment: @vancoder, I updated my answer with the hook